# How to cut off the screen in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: display

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with my laptop.
My laptop screen is cracked since I accidentally dropped it on the floor.
I can't see the upper-left corner of my screen.
Is it possible to cut off the display?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It may be machine specific but on my Dell pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> toggles between the laptop screen, the laptop screen and an attached screen together and solely the external screen.

You should be able to check which key combination is relevant to your laptop by either referring to the manual in paper format or online with google.